# Convert wireless accesspoint to adhoc node

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a TP link CPE610 wireless long range router. It is currently being used as an access point. 
Is it possible to convert it to a node in an adhoc network comprising of multiple raspberry pis?

The network is to support a swarm of robots in formation. The CPE610 is to be at the base for data monitoring and to ensure connectivity.

Comment: It's better for it to be an AP. APs double the diameter of the network because the clients only have to be in range of the AP, not each other. In an ad hoc (IBSS) network, everything needs to be in range of everything else. I don't think you can even overlay a mesh protocol on top of IBSS effectively. You might want to see if 802.11s or Wi-Fi EasyMesh meets your needs.

Comment: @spiff, check out the (B.A.T.M.A.N). protocol. "The Better Approach To Mobile Adhoc Networking." I believe that runs on top of adhoc modes...

Comment: @spiff, I was hoping to run OLSRD on the adhoc network to ensure connectivity.  Also, I want to ensure inter-drone connectivity even if the base fails, which wont be possible if base is acting as an access point.